# Maintain last viewed page after server post using $.mobile.changePage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I used `$.mobile.changePage("#page3")` in my code and designed as

```
/* Default.aspx */
<div data-role="page" id="page1">HomePage</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">Something</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
     <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="cmdsubmit_Click"/>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page4">Something</div>
```

In code behind

```
/* Default.cs */
cmdsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Open DB Connection
//Insert Records
//Status bind to label
}
```

I have written some DB process in button click event. My problem is when changed to 'page3' and clicked button, after the response 'page1' is displaying instead of 'page3'. But in URL showing as 'ActualURL#page3'. How can I maintain last viewed page 'page3'?

Comment: You need to give us a bigger example, this is not enough.

Comment: Could you detail what is part of "goes to the server and doing some DB process" ?